# Groovy http request, parse headers values

Tags: http, post, groovy, http-headers, httprequest

I'm sending HTTP request from application 1

```
http://localhost:8888/inputs/example-input?ProductId=49823&Orders_orderId=27759
```

to application 2.

And in application 2 I'm reciving plain string:

```
inputs/example-input?ProductId=49823&Orders_orderId=27759
```

I need to get values in they own variables as shown:

```
def productId = 49823
def orderId = 27759
```

Is there some groovy way to parse input string `inputs/example-input?ProductId=49823&Orders_orderId=27759`?

Comment: Please improve your question quality by providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That is the query string not the headers in terms of HTTP, incorrect terminology used, should improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the input *manually*, e.g.:

```
def input = "inputs/example-input?ProductId=49823&Orders_orderId=27759"
def parsed = input
    .split("\\?")[1]
    .split("&")
    .inject([:]) { m, e ->
        def arr = e.split("=")
        m[arr[0]] = arr[1]
        m
    }

def productId = parsed.ProductId
def orderId = parsed.Orders_orderId
assert productId == '49823'
assert orderId == '27759'
```